# Closed form expression for the integral

Tags: integration, gamma-function

Can someone help me find the integral of the following

$$f = \exp\Big(-\pi\lambda T^{2/\beta}r^2\int^\infty_0\frac{1}{1+v^{\beta/2}}dv\Big)$$

It is from the papers and the authors have posted the results in form of some $\Gamma$ function

The final result by authors is

$$ = \exp(-\lambda r^2T^{2/\beta }K(\beta))$$ and $K(\beta) = \frac{2\pi \Gamma(2/\beta)\Gamma(1-2/\beta)}{\beta}$

Serious EDIT: Actually as someone below mentioned there was a typo in the power of $v$ in the denominator. Not it is fixed. Extremely sorry for the trouble to those who tried the solution.

Comment: Have you tried wolfram alpha or another symbolic integrator?

Comment: nops. I use https://www.integral-calculator.com/ and it did not give me any result

Comment: Just tried both of them, both cannot answer :(

Comment: Could you give a link to the paper ? Do you need to integrate $f$ with  respect to $r$ ?

Comment: The link is : http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5226963/ and my concerned eq. is the simplified form of Eq. 2.6

Comment: Note that $\beta$ is some constant actually, it is a path-loss exponent for a wireless channel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) integral:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{1+v^{\beta/2}}
&=\frac2\beta\int_0^\infty\frac{v^{\frac2\beta-1}\,\mathrm{d}v}{1+v}\\
&=\frac2\beta\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac2\beta\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac2\beta\right)}{\Gamma(1)}\\[6pt]
&=\frac2\beta\Gamma\left(\frac2\beta\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac2\beta\right)
\end{align}
$$
Note that we are using the formula from that Wikipedia page that says

> $$ \operatorname{B}(x,y)=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}\,\mathrm{d}t $$

This would mean that
$$
K(\beta)=\frac{2\pi}\beta\Gamma\left(\frac2\beta\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac2\beta\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks @robjohn. Thanks for clarifying my mistake that it was actually $v^{\beta/2}$ and not the other way around. Can you please provide reference for the above calculation from integral to gamma function notation. I tried to look over web but could not find. Thanks again :)

Comment: Can you please pass me how $\Gamma (2/\beta)\Gamma (1-2/\beta)$ comes as I cannot find it on wikipedia or even after google. May be I am too tired to search it after a long day...extremely sorry for this lazinesss, but believe me I tried to look for it.

Comment: @Sjaffry: The formula highlighted is on the page that I linked above. In that formula we let $x=\frac2\beta$ and $y=1-\frac2\beta$.

Comment: Thanks...That was literally very silly of me... :(

Answer (score 2):

$$\int^\infty_0\frac{1}{1+v^{2/\beta}}\,dv=\frac{\pi  \beta}{2}   \csc \left(\frac{\pi  \beta }{2}\right)\qquad \text{if} \qquad 0<\Re(\beta )<2$$
By  Euler's reflection formula $$ \Gamma \left(1-z\right) \Gamma \left(z\right)=\frac \pi  {\sin(\pi z)}=\pi  \csc (\pi  z)$$
Use $z=\frac 2 \beta$ to get 
$$K(\beta)=\frac{2 \pi}\beta \Gamma \left(1-\frac{2}{\beta }\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{\beta
   }\right)=\frac{\pi  \beta}{2}   \csc \left(\frac{\pi  \beta }{2}\right)\qquad \text{if} \qquad 0<\Re(\beta )<2$$ I seems that a $\pi$ is missing somewhere in $f$.

Comment: Somewhere, $\frac\beta2$ got changed to $\frac2\beta$.

Comment: @robjohn. In my answer or in the question ?

Comment: I don't think $\Gamma\left(\frac2\beta\right)$ and $\Gamma\left(1-\frac2\beta\right)$ are correct. So I guess in both.